# Excel Sum extracted numbers from text string

Tags: arrays, string, excel, sum, countif

Somebody could help me with this problem? I need to extract the numbers from a text string and then Sum them with a single formula.

The 3 first caracters of the string are always the same:

A::23

A::4

A::8

A::10

A::44

To remove the alphanumeric caracters I use =MID(A1,3,2), however this formula works well for every single cell only.

I am trying to create a formula that will Sum all the extracted numbers of a given range.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(0+RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A5,":",REPT(" ",17)),17))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

`{=SUM(VALUE(MID($A$1:$A$5,4,2)))}`

to enter the function press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Edit:

`{=SUM(MID($A$1:$A$5,4,2)*1)}`

also works

Answer (score 0):

=SUMPRODUCT(VALUE(MID(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)))

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding some explanation, code markup and/or documentation links.